# Nullify properties from within property object

Tags: c#, wpf

If properties in multiple objects are referring to the same object instance, how can I nullify those references from within the object instance?

Example:

```
class Main {
    private SignalHandler _signalHandler;
    public IndicatorData Indicator1 { get; set; }
    public IndicatorData Indicator2 { get; set; }
    public IndicatorData Indicator3 { get; set; }

    public Main() {
        _signalHandler = new SignalHandler();
        _signalHandler.SignalList.Add(new Signal());
        _signalHandler.SignalList.Add(new Signal());
        Indicator1 = new IndicatorData() { Name = "Indicator 1",
                                           Signal = _signalHandler.SignalList[0] };
        Indicator2 = new IndicatorData() { Name = "Indicator 2",
                                           Signal = _signalHandler.SignalList[1] };
        Indicator3 = new IndicatorData() { Name = "Indicator 3",
                                           Signal = _signalHandler.SignalList[0] };

        // Indicators binding to Signal.Value property in Indicator1 and Indicator3
        // now gets updated through INotifyPropertyChanged.
        _signalHandler.SignalList[0].Value = 123;

        // Removing first element from the SignalList.
        _signalHandler.SignalList[0].Remove();
    }
}

class SignalHandler {
    public SignalHandler() {
        SignalList = new List<Signal>();
    }
    public List<Signal> SignalList { get; set; }
}

class IndicatorData {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Signal Signal { get; set; }
}

class Signal {
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public void Remove() {
        // How can I now set all properties referring
        // to the Value property above to null?
    }
}
```

EDIT: To elaborate, I have a collection of Signal objects that I use as storage places for incoming data.  Indicators can bind to the Signal object's Value property, which will be updated in the UI through INotifyPropertyChanged (not in this example).  What I want is that if the user removes the Signal object from the SignalList, the various properties referring to that Signal object should reflect this.

Comment: That's sounds like a weird OOP pattern. Could you instead tell us what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Seems like a total mess to me. Why would you even want more than one property to reference the exact same instance? that doesn't make sense.

Comment: A variable references an object, an object doesn't reference a variable

Comment: Please see edits to question.  @ZoharPeled It does make sense if you have several indicators you want to bind to the same value.

Comment: So once you remove the first signal from the list, Indicator1 and Indicator1 should have only names (with the signal property set to null), or should they become null? (the indicators themselves, I mean)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, the first one, with signal property set to null. The idea is to have one writer and one or more readers of the signal. If I just remove the Signal object from the list, it still exists and gets referenced to. I figured I need to dispose of the object or nullify references to it in some way.

Comment: Since you're using `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I suppose you're in the WPF world. If that's right, then all your problems can be solved by correctly applying the MVVM concept: use views and view-models connected by Data Bindings. They will do the job. If you want, I can create a small example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This started out as a comment but it's getting too long, and I also think it might point you to the direction you want to go:

I'm guessing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface you mentioned is implemented on the `Signal` class.
I think you should change the `List` to an `ObservableCollection`. That will enable you to handle events when adding or removing items from the collection.
Then you can add a property to the `Signal` class indicating if it's in the collection or not.
From there it's quite easy to use the `PropertyChanged` event in the `IndicatorData` class and nullify the signal if it's removed from the collection.
The one thing that might be problematic here is that nothing is stopping you from adding the same signal to multiple collections (if you have multiple instances of `SignalHandler` that handles the same `Signal` instance).

Comment: Yes, I'm using INotifyPropertyChanged (or rather BindableBase, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged (https://www.danrigby.com/2015/09/12/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-6-way/)).  I'm also using ObservableCollection - just wanted to keep the example simple.

In any event, I really like your idea.  To just have a "kill" property in the Signal object fire off a notification, and have the referencing objects nullify their references rather than attempt to do it from within the Signal object.

Comment: But for the hell of it, is it even possible to do what I originally asked about?  Is it possible for an object to "find" which parent objects that have properties referencing to it?

Comment: Not without writing specific code for that. There is nothing that changes the object state when adding or removing it from a collection.